# How to use &amp in tuckey outbound rules in Struts 2

Tags: java, regex, url-rewriting, struts2, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I'm having trouble with Tuckey URL outbound rules.
We are using Tuckey with Struts2.

**Outbound rule:**

```xml
<outbound-rule>
    <from>^/articleList\?category=(\d*)&amp;page=(\d*)(;jsessionid=.*)?$</from>
    <to last="true">/list/$1/$2</to>
</outbound-rule>
```

**JSP:**

```xml
<a href="<s:url value="/articleList" ><s:param name="category"
value="#article.category" /><s:param name="page" value="1" /></s:url>"    target="_blank[articlelist]</a>
```

Although it says processing outbound rule it's not forwarding to my URL.
In the `url-rewritestatus` it shows all my rules but doesn't show matched ones.
debug log:

```
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter DEBUG: processing outbound url for /articleList?category=3&amp;page=1
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleBase DEBUG: Outbound Rule 0 run called with /articleList?category=3&amp;page=1
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleBase DEBUG: Outbound Rule 1 run called with /articleList?category=3&amp;page=1
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleBase DEBUG: Outbound Rule 2 run called with /articleList?category=3&amp;page=1
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleBase DEBUG: Outbound Rule 3 run called with /articleList?category=3&amp;page=1
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleBase DEBUG: Outbound Rule 4 run called with /articleList?category=3&amp;page=1
```

debuging the source I see

```
url:/articleList?category=1&amp;page=1
pattern:^/articleList\?category=(\d*)&page=(\d*)(;jsessionid=.*)?$
```

What I am doing wrong?

evn:`struts2 + spring3  jetty`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have escaped `&` symbol in the url and you see in the source code it's `&amp;`. This doesn't allow the pattern to match the url. Try to change the pattern to match both escaped and unescaped ampersand.

```xml
<from>^/articleList\?category=(\d*)(\&|&amp;){1}page=(\d*)(;jsessionid=.*)?$</from>
```

Comment: add option [escapeAmp = "false"] to s:url and fix it